# Why element locators are not suggested in visual studio code for protractor?

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, jasmine

I don't get suggestions for "element(by." element locators in visual studio code. Im using protractor. I have changed the settings file also.

Settings.js

```
{
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
},

// Controls if suggestions should be accepted on 'Enter' - in addition to 'Tab'. Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines or accepting suggestions. The value 'smart' means only accept a suggestion with Enter when it makes a textual change
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",

// Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,

// Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,

// Controls if pressing tab inserts the best suggestion and if tab cycles through other suggestions
"editor.tabCompletion": "on",

// Controls whether sorting favours words that appear close to the cursor
"editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,

// Controls how suggestions are pre-selected when showing the suggest list
"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",

// Enable word based suggestions
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,

// Enable parameter hints
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,
}
```

Please help fix this intellisense issuer

Comment: Voting for closing because this is related to VS Code configuration - IMO it should placed in Stack Overflow

Comment: It's related to the Testing and he is asking about locator suggestion's are not showing in Visual Studio as like Eclipse, so this could be best fit here. Which version are you using?

Comment: are you using javascript or typescript?

Comment: Has anyone been able to answer this conclusively? Eclipse is another rabbit hole for configuration in JS and VS Code is just better visually for JS. However, the IntelliSense for Protractor just does not work even on installing the runner like he suggests

Comment: Should be closed.  The issue with testing is real however, as last line indicates this is an issue with *intellisense* not with testing.  Good question just the wrong forum for it.

Answer (score -1):

Please watch this video, It has the detailed info to get auto suggestion in vs code for protractor:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywn5nBm-1vU

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731